# Can't get android layout to do what I want

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I've spent years working with GridBagLayout in java, so I thought setting up a simple layout would be easy. After hours of fiddling with nested LinearLayouts, reading tutorials, and looking at RelativeLayout, I'm getting nowhere.

Below is what I want my main menu to look like. I assume this is possible to do, but many things do not make sense to me, for instance increasing **weights** seems to decrease the amount of space that a View takes up?

One thing I'm considering doing is just using a relative layout, laying everything else without caring about sizes, and then just setting the sizes in my onCreate since I'll know the size of the display and I can just set each element a certain number of pixels. Is that considered bad practice?

I'm just trying to create a layout with a title on top (the text as large it is can be to fill the width of the screen). That should take up the top 30%. Then the next 50% contains two buttons on the left, an area where I want to draw some animations (I assume using a SurfaceView is a good idea), and then two more buttons on the right.

The remaining 20% will be for a banner ad once I figure out how to add those in.

Is this possible to do? Can anyone show me some XML for this?

[image: my design]

Comment: You will have to use a combination of layouts, the general layout could be a linear layout using a vertical orientation, and using the weights to give you the 30/50/20 distribution. The middle portion could be a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, or a RelativeLayout maybe?

Comment: Thanks Gosu, but the problem was not setting the weights to 0px (see below).

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Alok Nair, this was not hard to do ... I just had to set the sizes to 0px and let the layout weights take care of the sizing.

This is what it ended up being:

[image: preview image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/main_menu_background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/mainSectionMenu"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="LUNA PUMA"
        android:id="@+id/mTitleText"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight=".5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:text="Easy"
                android:id="@+id/mEasyButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:text="Medium"
                android:id="@+id/mMediumButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mAnimationSurfaceView"
            android:layout_weight=".5"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:text="Hard"
                android:id="@+id/mHardButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:text="More ..."
                android:id="@+id/mMoreButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight=".2">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a combination of layouts, and to achieve this you can use either use android:layout_weight parameters to your views or use Android Percent Support Library.

With layout_weight you can specify a size ratio between multiple views. E.g. you have a view1 and a view2. The view1 should use 3/4 of the screen and view2 should use 1/4 of the screen. Then you will set the layout_weight of the view1 to 3 and the layout_weight of the view2 to 1.

To get it work you also have to set the height or width (depending on your orientation) to 0px.

The **Android Percent Support Library** allows to specify dimensions of views in terms of percentages instead of absolute numbers, or weights.

The library consists of two main layouts which allow nested views to specify percentage based layouts: PercentRelativeLayout and PercentFrameLayout which work much like their non-Percent counterparts.

Once you've incorporated one of these containers into your layout you can then specify attributes in percentages such as app:layout_widthPercent or app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%".

For using it in your app, just add percent support library to your project

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
}
```

Here is an example layout using this lib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    style="@style/match"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    style="@style/block"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_one_item_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#5182bb"
        app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="30%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_one_item_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_one_item_one"
        android:background="#396190"
        app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="30%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_one_item_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_one_item_two"
        android:background="#8fb5e1"
        app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_two_item_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_one_item_one"
        android:background="#d89695"
        app:layout_heightPercent="15%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_three_item_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_two_item_one"
        android:background="#f9c093"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_three_item_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_two_item_one"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_three_item_one"
        android:background="#948957"
        app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="60%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_four_item_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_three_item_one"
        android:background="#ccc2d9"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_four_item_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_three_item_two"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_four_item_one"
        android:background="#c3d59e"
        app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="60%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_five_item_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_four_item_one"
        android:background="#948957"
        app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_five_item_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_four_item_two"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_five_item_one"
        android:background="#e6e0ec"
        app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="60%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_six_item_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_five_item_one"
        android:background="#f9c093"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_six_item_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_five_item_one"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_six_item_one"
        android:background="#588fd3"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/row_six_item_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_five_item_two"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_six_item_two"
        android:background="#a6a6a6"
        app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="60%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

You can get idea from this and use it to implement for your design requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the key part I was missing: To get it work you also have to set the height or width (depending on your orientation) to 0px. I'll edit my question with what I ended up doing.

Comment: This really helps! I don't think it's unrealistic to say that stackoverflow improves my productivity by 2x-3x!